# Should one not go through a user's posts up/down/close voting?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, serial-voting

If a user posts a bad question which is VTC/DV worthy, every now and then I'll look through their other posts. Often these other posts additionally lack the quality we strive for on this site and should be dealt with in a similar way (or even upvoted if they're good). However, currently I do not take any action as I do not want to be seen by the automated system (or even the user (albeit anonymously)) to be revenge voting/bullying (which of course is not the case).

What is the correct course of action? To ignore and hope The System deals with these posts over time, or to actively vote on these questions as I would normally throughout the site ignoring the fact I am pivoting around a single user?

Comment: Downvoting is explicitly disallowed and reverted by the serial voting script. There's no such thing for closevotes though, so I'd say you're free to closevote any crap you come across.

Answer (score 7):

By going through a profile and voting on posts associated with that profile, you're essentially concentrating your votes on that user, at least for the period of time you are spending on their posts. However, for up- and down-votes the system cannot identify intent, and so it will err on the side of caution and reverse them. There is no mechanism for close votes though - but that doesn't make it right to go though voting to close posts just because of who asked them.

Really, the only advice we can give is to not go through someone's posts like that. If a user is consistently posting poorly, that will usually be taken care of by the community.

Comment: You should clarify that you're talking about _downvotes_ here, not close votes.

Comment: @l4mpi - even with close votes you are targeting the user, so this still applies

Comment: @ChrisF but this post implies the system does something against it, which afaik is not true.

Comment: @l4mpi I would say that system does _something_, although it's different than in case of regular votes (and likely more efficient). Votes to close and delete aren't anonymous and pass peer review, that makes serially doing these much less troublesome. To get several high-rep peers agree with your votes and have your name clearly visible in closed / deleted post makes much less room for potential abuse